# How do I get request object with other params using ruby on rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Currently I am working on project like web analytic using rails 3.2.3

I have two server, one is running on `port 3001` and other one running on `port 3000`.

Here **port 3001 is the server (let's say this is Google web analytic server)** and **port 3000 server is the end user (let's say this is your site)**. Now I need to get
request object from port 3000.

If I will write below code I can get the Browser details.

application.html.erb    - This is user side code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://localhost:3001/tracks/track_client?bwname=<%= request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  %>">
</script>
```

This is the server side coce

```
def track_client
 params.each do |key,value|
  Rails.logger.warn "Param #{key}: #{value}"
 end
end

{bwname=>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1", " WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2}
```

**But I need user's request object with all properties not specific.** like I need other properties too like

```
"GATEWAY_INTERFACE", "PATH_INFO", "QUERY_STRING", "REMOTE_ADDR", "REMOTE_HOST", "REQUEST_METHOD", "REQUEST_URI", "SCRIPT_NAME", "SERVER_NAME", "SERVER_PORT", "SERVER_PROTOCOL", "SERVER_SOFTWARE", "HTTP_HOST", "HTTP_USER_AGENT",
"HTTP_ACCEPT",  "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE",  "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING",  "HTTP_DNT"=>"1",  "HTTP_CONNECTION", "HTTP_COOKIE", "HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH", "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"
```

Along with this I need some other params too like something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://localhost:3001/tracks/track_client?userid=1234&bwname=<%= request.env %>">
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of these two different ports? What do you mean "port 3000 server is the user"?

Comment: let's say port 3001 run server code (it's clone of google web analytic concept) and port 3000 run user site, means end user site.

on one computer I am checking these. so one is server and other is client, that way I am using different port

Comment: what is the purpose of that to side did you want to make something like chatting application?
and are you using any gem for server and client communication?

Comment: Have you using HTTP Request and Response or simple TCP/UDP?
If you are using TCP/UDP then you can use socket programming.I hope this will help you.

Comment: @urjitrajgor - I am talking about Clone of Google web analytic server and Client. Not Chatting application. See the response of Hungry Coder that's something perfect way. Now I have a way - just need to start. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `request` object?

Please check here
http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/25-rails-request-environment-variables

Comment: I need request object for end user, not the server. means I need request object for server port 3000, and I am on port 3001.

Comment: Well, if 3000 port application is your then you can expose the request object through a js variable and make an async request to your server or you can make a server to server request with the data. But if you are going to make, as said in examples, something like google analytics, i believe you will have to do these using javascript. Sorry if could not help you.

Comment: This one is correct way - I will try working on this. Thanks for the response.